# Getting multi-dimensional array value using Javascript / node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have an Object that looks like this>

```
let arr = [
    ['animal','lion'],
    ['plant','rose'],
    ['tree','coconut'],
]
```

I want to make my code look like this:

```
['animal','lion']
['plant','rose']
['tree','coconut']
```

For this, I tried this method:

```
let sep1=arr[0];
let sep2=arr[1];
```

Getting value as:

```
['animal','lion']
['plant','rose']
```

I have to repeat the code 3 time to get the output, but what if there is 30 arrays inside an object? Any solution?

*Ps*: I am weak in coding bear with me :slight_smile:

Comment: I think you are trying to flatten the array? You mean like this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: You could use destructuring: `const [sep1, sep2, sep3] = arr;` but if there could be like 30 nested arrays, why do you want to save a reference to each nested array in a separate variable?

Comment: If the array has 30 members, then yes, you will need 30 variables. Just use the nested array, it's rarely useful to explode a big array to variables. If you really need the members assigned into variables, use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: try this `arr.flatMap(el => console.log(el));` the above solutions will also work, but if you have this array where values assigned dynamically `flatmap` is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access the separate arrays by `key`, you could `map()` through your array and create `entries` to create an object from. That way, you could access a specific array by `property key`.

```js
let arr = [
  ['animal', 'lion'],
  ['plant', 'rose'],
  ['tree', 'coconut'],
];


const result = Object.fromEntries(arr.map((a, i) => {
  return [`sep${i}`, a]; // return ['sepX', [x, x]] as entries
}));

console.log("result", result);
console.log("sep0", result.sep0);
console.log("sep1", result.sep1);
console.log("sep2", result.sep2);
```